# Module type default in Firefox

Tags: firefox, ecmascript-6

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this.  I've googled this and not really finding the results.  I'm using ES6 modules and import/export and load my initial javascript using module type

```
<script type="module" src="/app.js"></script>
```

In Chrome its on by default.  In firefox you have to enable it in about:config

[image]

The problem is I cant have users manually enabling this flag for it to work.  Is there a future where this will be on by default in Firefox?  At [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module), it says that in version 60, its on by default.  But every version of Firefox I've downloaded is only version 59.00 (Windows).  I would like to avoid babel if possible.

[image]

Comment: Module syntax is still brand new. It is not ready for production use without also including a fallback to a non-module bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a future where this will be on by default in Firefox?

Yes.

> At CanIUse, it says that in version 60, its on by default. But every version of Firefox I've downloaded is only version 59.00 (Windows).

You can download the nightly build [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/60.0a1/releasenotes/).

> I would like to avoid Babel if possible.

Well you cannot avoid if you want to support older browsers that do not (yet) support this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I only really care about Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Safari.  It looks like it going to be released in May so that is perfect.  Thank you